# How to Copy & Paste a renamed sheet as values

Tags: excel, vba

My goal is to copy and paste over a sheet as values in VBA, and rename the sheet as cell 'B7' in my newly copy/pasted sheet.

So far I have managed to copy and paste the sheet with the name set as 'B7' with the following code:

```
Sub RenameSheets()
'Updateby Extendoffice
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set wh = Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name)
    ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count)
    If wh.Range("B7").Value <> "" Then
    ActiveSheet.Name = wh.Range("B7").Value
    End If
    wh.Activate
End Sub
```

I am not sure how to copy and paste the new sheet over as values though, and it retains all the formulas from the sheet I'm copying from...

I appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Comment: After the copy these 3 more lines: `ActiveSheet.Cells.Copy, ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlValues, Application.CutCopyMode = False`

Comment: `ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value`.

Comment: @BigBen thank you, this worked perfectly for me!